# ILMerge using 2 third party dll's C++

Tags: c++, ilmerge

I have written a program that utilizes 2 3rd party dll's and I want to use ILMerge to merge both dll's into 1 executable.
I have tried using the command line:

```
ilmerge /target:winexe /out:final.exe normal.exe 3rd_party_dll_1.dll 3rd_party_dll_2.dll
```

but this returns this error:

```
`Could not load assembly from the location 'C:\Users\...' Skipping and processing trest of arguments. `
```

Am I missing something or is it possible that these dll's cannot be merged?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ILMerge doesn't work on native dlls out of the box, but there is a [workaround](http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/archive/2007/02/04/single-assembly-deployment-of-managed-and-unmanaged-code.aspx).

Comment: what do you mean "native dlls"?

Comment: @Nick Dlls which are written not in .net

Comment: it is a Win32 MFC dll. I thought this would still work. Thanks.