# Embedding\Merging .NET v1 Assemblies on .NET v4+ Assembly

Tags: c#, ilmerge

I have a C# library with some assemblies developed by us and some third-party o I need put everything in a single assembly file.

When I try to **merge** everything using ILMerge I got the following error:

> An exception occurred during merging:
>
> ILMerge.Merge: The assembly 'TestLibrary' is not marked as
>   containing only managed code.   (Consider using the /zeroPeKind option
>   -- but read the documentation first!)
>        em ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
>        em ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)

When I remove TestLibrary from the Merge, it works fine. But to get my project working I have reference the TestLibrary separately and enable useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true".

So, after a little more research I decided to try using Embedded Resources using [Jeffrey Richter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) => {
   String resourceName = "AssemblyLoadingAndReflection." +
      new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
   using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)) {
      Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];
      stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
      return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
   }
};
```

It loads the resource bytes but fails on Assembly.Load saying that the program have a incorrect format.

The TestLibrary is a C++ .Net v1.0 Library.

Comment: The error message seems fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: I never understood why ILMerge is so popular.  Merging assemblies into a single EXE is already so well supported by VS with no restrictions at all.  The final file is named setup.exe, surely you've used them before.  Add a Setup project to your solution.

Comment: @hans-passant I know this is OT, but we use it for our internal framework / libraries. We have a bunch of projects that do fancy stuff, then merge them into a single DLL for use in our applications. This makes life easier for us as it reduces the number of required dependencies, and "hides" external utilities (eg, restsharp) we don't want exposed to the calling application. We don't merge the assemblies for the application being deployed, rather we use setup.exe or a similar alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ILMerge simply cannot deal with assemblies containing native code. You must either extract the dll at runtime prior to use, or ship the dll. This is also explained at [ILMerge using 2 third party dll's C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910356/ilmerge-using-2-third-party-dlls-c)